# Remove selected index from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I figured out how to put in array of selected elements when i click on row and i see `.checkmark`. And if i click the second time i see checkmark `.none`, but how i can **remove** selected elements from my array on which i clicked the second time?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if (cell?.accessoryType == .checkmark) {
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
            print("deselect - \(titleOptions[indexPath.row])")

            // how to remove selectedIndex from array???
            selectedIndexArray....

            print("\(selectedIndexArray)")
        } else {
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            print("select - \(titleOptions[indexPath.row])")
            selectedIndexArray.append(titleOptions[indexPath.row])
            print("\(selectedIndexArray)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `selectedIndexArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)`

Comment: @Priya App will crash with that code !! , if he have only 3 item in array and press uncheck on 4th cell

Comment: You need to manage dictionary instead of array , key would be indexPath.row or Other unique id to identify cell , and value is True or false

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes, app is crash

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев Try Dictionary instead of array !! like self.dict[indexPath.row] = true / false

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya a little don't understand :( can explain for dummies? :)

Comment: You have to delete that object and it can be any index path so to do that you have to do something like this  let object = selectedIndexArray[indexPath.row];
        if let index = selectedIndexArray.index(of: object) {
            selectedIndexArray.remove(at: index);
        }

Comment: 1)   `var dict:[IndexPath:Bool] = [:]`

Comment: 2) In cellForRow  `if let selected = dict[indexPath],selected == true {
            //check mark
        } else {
            // None
        }`

Comment: 3) In DidSelect row         `if let selected = dict[indexPath],selected == true {
            //check mark
            dict[indexPath] = false
        } else {
            // None
            dict[indexPath] = true
        }`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i will try, thanks